# Running kivy on android for windows

Tags: android, python, windows, kivy

I decided to make an android app using python, therefore i installed kivy. now i have python 3.4 and kivy, but i can't figure out for the love of god how to package for android. I spent to much time and effort going through online guides that don't work.

I came across something called 'buildozer', but apparently that's only for linux, so the whole world is against me programming kivy for android.

ps. i got windows 8, python 3.4 and kivy. That's it. I am looking for the easiest, fastest method of getting this done.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Kivy's build tools run only on linux and osx.

From windows, you can run a linux virtual machine (running linux). The Kivy project provides one as documented [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html), but actually this may be a little out of date. brousch (one of the core devs) has a new, improved one that you can find [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html), but I'm not sure exactly where the build tools are in it.